# Stick number of Trefoil

Tags: proof-verification, knot-theory, knot-invariants

So it is well know that the stick number (i.e. the minimum number that is need to make a knot out of -not necessarily of the same length- sticks) of every non-trivial knot is above six, with only the trefoil ataining the minimum. But it seems that I have found a counter example. [image]

Since we can trecolor it the knot is not trivial and also since it has exactly 3 crossings it is the trefoil. What am I missing ?

Comment: That's a good question you can answer with an experiment. Try to construct a trefoil knot with sticks according to this diagram, and you should see the obstruction.

Comment: @D.Thomine First of all: So this means that the stick number is something *physical* in the sense that is not **just** the number of straigh lines you need to realize the kntot. Second: I have tried with straws. While indeed the curve , I am not convinced that this would still happen if I could have ε-thin sticks. Any idea how one could disprove me formaly ?

Comment: The definition is not physical in itself, but it corresponds pretty well to our physical intuition,whence the usefulness of an experiment.

Comment: Now, for a proof : start with the upper-most segment. Say it is horizontal. Add the two adjacent segments. One must go upwards (the right one with your diagram), the other downwards. Finally, add the last two segments. With your diagram, the red one start from below (down-right point), and goes upwards ; the other starts from above and goes downwards. But then, these last two segment cannot meet, because the red one will be above the green-red one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be dealing with an invariant that is similar to but not quite the stick number.  If I understand your invariant, you are taking all knot diagrams made of only straight lines and finding the minimum number of straight lines in any such diagram.  Your example shows that for the trefoil this invariant is at most $5$.

The stick number, on the other hand, has to do with piecewise linear embeddings of the circle into 3D space, and it is the minimum number of line segments in any such parameterization.  Your example does not correspond to a piecewise linear embedding in 3D.  It has a sort of Penrose triangle paradox if you try to lift it to 3D.